# Does there exist some kind of irreversible transfomations on maths?

Tags: soft-question, notation

I know that this kind of transformation by itself without control can lead to contradiction because its value changes depending on the state of the function where you do the transformation. Anyway I want to show my idea:

$$F^k\rightarrow k!$$

Some kind of symbol that it exponent, that it takes on normal exponentiation operations of normal algebra, can be transformed after **in a specific moment** in an irreversible transformation, i.e., in a function that represents a different thing non-linear as a factorial.

We have, for example, a generating function like

$$f(x)=(1+ax+ax^2+ax^3)(1+ax^3+ax^5)=a^{2} x^{8} + a^{2} x^{7} + 2 \, a^{2} x^{6} + a^{2} x^{5} + a^{2} x^{4} + a x^{5} + 2 \, a x^{3} + a x^{2} + a x + 1$$

then, in some moment, I want to transform the $a^k$ coefficients in $k!$ to express permutations

$$f(x)\rightarrow(a^k\to k!)\to 2! x^{8} + 2! x^{7} + 2\cdot 2! x^{6} + 2! x^{5} + 2! x^{4} + x^{5} + 2 x^{3} +  x^{2} + x + 1 $$

I could add another power to express duplicated permutations ($c^k=\frac{1}{k!}$) over groups that I consider equals and lead to repeated patterns.

Is there a symbology or method to do this kind of task?

Comment: Is this only defined on polynomials? How would $\frac1{x^2+1}$ react?

Comment: In the same way Alizter. But in your expression isnt any kind of coefficients as I describe on the question, just a power of x. The idea is to know if exist some kind of notation for irreversible manipulation of formulas.

Comment: To map $a^k\mapsto k!$ one might tinvestigate sumething like $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{d^n}{da^n}f|_{a=0}$ perhaps

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen if I understand correctly the summation just leave the formula when any $a^0=1$ and let any power of $x$ multiplied by the factorial. Yes, it seems a good way to express in a simbology with math sense what I was searching for.